# How to evaluate "At Least" in a logic statement "There are at least three undefined terms in Geometry."

Tags: logic

Given the fact that there are exactly 3 undefined terms in Geometry, how would one evaluate the following statement as being true or false:

"There are at least three undefined terms in Geometry."

Comment: Hint: Sometimes it is helpful to formulate an intermediate statement in a logical form - it may help to consider a statement of the form "There exist three ... " in relation to what you already have. Maybe overcomplicated here, but helpful in a more complex case ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are *exactly 3 foobars,* is it true or false if I say to you, "there are at least 3 foobars?"

What do you think?

Comment: I would say yes, it's true.  My argument is "at least" means 3 or more and since there are 3 foobars, the statement is true.  However, the counter-argument I'm hearing is "at least" implies  that not only 3 is a valid solution, but also 4, and 5 , and so on, which is not true. And the rule is that if a logic statement implies that something is true which is not true, then the entire statement is deemed to be false.

Comment: @Kevin You are right in your first argument: yes it is true. To address that "counter-argument", no, saying there are at least 3 foobars does NOT imply that 4, 5, etc. are "valid solutions". It just says I'm not ruling them out. It is not *false* to say there are at least 3 foobars if there are exactly 3, but it is *less specific* than saying there are exactly 3.

Comment: If somebody asks you "do we have any beer" and you look in the fridge and see some bottles of Pabst, you might say "yes", but here is a counter-argument: "beer" implies that Pabst is a valid solution, but so is Samuel Adams or Coors or Lowenbrau, so the entire statement "we have beer" is deemed to be false.

Comment: @bof I like the beer example, but re: your second comment, OP wasn't defining "at least three" to mean "exactly three", I think he/she was defining it to mean "3 or more and we're not sure how many" (which is a meta notion). I don't see how you understood it as two ways to say exactly 3, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either. Guess I had one too many beers.

Comment: Actually, under that silly interpretation, "there are at least 3 foobars" would never be true.

Comment: I wasn't defining "at least three" to mean anything. Rather the core of my question was if there's a commonly accepted definition of "at least".

Comment: The commonly accepted definition of "at least three" is "three or more". What else could it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is (obviously) true that `at least three` includes the case `exactly three`.

Your question seems to revolve around the `*given the fact* that there are exactly 3` part. It is true that for example `there are *at least* two equinoxes a year` would be an odd thing to say, though still *not* technically false.

In math however it often makes sense to make such (under)statements. Suppose for example that a complicated proof ended up hanging on $P(x)=x^3-4 x^2+9 x-10$ having a real root. It would be perfectly normal to conclude with "*by inspection* $x=2$ *is a root so* $P(x)$ *has at least one real root Q.E.D.*" even though `the fact` is $P(x)$ has *exactly* one root.

Answer (score 0):

You should evaluate true.

The numerical quantification was introduced by Frege to express numbers with logical notation. The sentence '***There are at least three undefined terms in Geometry***' is formalized as follows ('Gx' is for 'x is primitive in Geometry'):

∃x∃y∃z (x≠y & x≠z & y≠z & Gx & Gy & Gz)

The logical form shows that if **there is less than three G**, then the sentence is false (because 'x≠y & x≠z & y≠z' would be false); and, if **there is more than three G**, then the sentence is **true** (because no member of the conjunction 'x≠y & x≠z & y≠z & Gx & Gy & Gz' would be false).

If you mean that '**There are *exactly* three G**', the logical form is more complex:

∃x∃y∃z(x≠y & x≠z & y≠z & Gx & Gy & Gz & ∀w(Gw → w=x ∨ w=y ∨ w=z))

In this case, the sentence its true if and only if no more and no less than three G: if **there is less than three G** then 'x≠y & x≠z & y≠z' would be false; and, if **there is more than three G**, then '∀w(Gw → w=x ∨ w=y ∨ w=z)' would be false).

Comment: Correct, but seems a bit overkill / too technical.